# Connecting to Astra DB, withCloudSecureConnectBundle() returns java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, cassandra, datastax-astra

I am trying to connect to Astra DB which requires a path to secure-connect zip.

This line is causing the issue:

```
.withCloudSecureConnectBundle(Paths.get("E:\\ProjectAndroid\\9_14_2022_2\\RentPK\\app\\src\\main\\res\\secure-connect-rentpk"))
```

Path.get gives the error.

I wanted to connect Astra DB using secure-connect zip but `Paths.get()` not working for the given path. Where the path is:
`E:\\ProjectAndroid\\9_14_2022_2\\RentPK\\app\\src\\main\\res\\secure-connect-rentpk`

Comment: Can you list that directory and show us the result so we can see that the file really exists there?

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:android-studio] (which should almost certainly be [tag:android], since this question doesn't seem IDE specific). If this is supposed to run on Android, then that path will not work, because `E:\ProjectAndroid\...` is obviously a Window path and doesn't exist on Android.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't provided the full name for the secure bundle. In your sample code, you've specified the filename as `secure-connect-rentpk` which is incorrect.

You need to make sure that you include the `.zip` suffix in the filename and don't unzip the bundle leaving it intact. For example:

```
    .withCloudSecureConnectBundle(Paths.get("/path/to/secure-connect-db.zip"))
```

As a side note, you should never include the secure bundle in your source code. You need to place it in a separate location such as a configuration folder for best practice. Cheers!